# what javascript to simulate tab, enter or comma input for jquery.tokeninput?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tokenize

Anybody know [jquery.tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)? What combination of (jQuery) events do I use (presumably on the input field) to simulate the effect of entering text and pressing tab, enter or the comma key when the `allowFreeTagging` option is true?

I'm able to simulate field entry and click selection, like with the following:

```
$("#token-input-interests").focus();
$("#token-input-interests").val('#{typed_in_val}');
$("#token-input-interests").keydown();
...
```

But I don't succeed when swapping out click for key events.

thx,

Lille

Answer (score 0):

In general, trying to simulate user action it is not a very good thing. user action is an action of....user, and not JS code. And for security reason I'm glad that is difficult or impossible.

But, if you read the documentation, it seems that the plugin provides some basic and useful methods to do the job :

```
    $("YOUR_SELECTOR").tokenInput("add", {id: x, name: y});
```

this one allow you to simulate an add with x as identifier and y as value.

So, try to use it in order to add pre-entered values.

You also have other functions like:

```
    $("YOUR_SELECTOR").tokenInput("remove", {id: x});
    //to remove an entry by id

    $("YOUR_SELECTOR").tokenInput("remove", {name: y});
    // to remove an entry by value

    $("YOUR_SELECTOR").tokenInput("clear");
    // to clear the list

    $("YOUR_SELECTOR").tokenInput("get");
    // to retrieve an array of selection object like
    // [{id: x, name: y},{id: x, name: y},{id: x, name: y}]
```

Comment: I seek to simulate user action in my tests. The functions to which you refer do not allow me to resemble the action of interest -- key input -- in my tests.